# Roslyn-Find Unused variables

Tags: c#, roslyn

I would like to get all **unused variables** in my solution and I have the below code *working except for one scenario*.

**E.g.**

```
Int64 num;
Int64.TryParse("1234", out num);
```

My code detects `num` variable also as an unused variable. How could I avoid this? any suggestions.

**Code:**

```
public async Task<List<Location>> GetUnusedLocalVariables(Solution solution)
        {
            List<Location> locations = new List<Location>();
            foreach (var pjt in solution.Projects)
            {
                var compilation = await pjt.GetCompilationAsync();
                foreach (var tree in compilation.SyntaxTrees)
                {
                    var methods = tree.GetRoot().DescendantNodesAndSelf().OfType<MethodDeclarationSyntax>().Where(x => x.IsKind(SyntaxKind.MethodDeclaration));
                    foreach (var method in methods)
                    {
                        if (method.Body == null) continue;
                        var dataFlow = compilation.GetSemanticModel(tree).AnalyzeDataFlow(method.Body);
                        var variablesDeclared = dataFlow.VariablesDeclared.Where(x => x.Kind.ToString() == "Local");
                        var variablesRead = dataFlow.ReadInside.Union(dataFlow.ReadOutside);
                        var unused = variablesDeclared.Except(variablesRead);
                        if (unused.Any())
                        {
                            foreach (var unusedVar in unused)
                            {
                                var foreachStatements = method.DescendantNodes().OfType<ForEachStatementSyntax>().Where(x => x.Identifier.Text == unusedVar.Name).ToList();
                                if (foreachStatements?.Count > 0) continue;
                                locations.Add(unusedVar.Locations.First());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return locations;
        }
```

**UPDATE:**
Below is the exact code where my `GetUnusedLocalVariables` has detected `formatters` as an unused variable.

**HelpPageSampleGenerator.cs (Autogenerated code in my web api project)**

```
public virtual Type ResolveHttpRequestMessageType(ApiDescription api)
        {
            string controllerName = api.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
            string actionName = api.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            IEnumerable<string> parameterNames = api.ParameterDescriptions.Select(p => p.Name);
            Collection<MediaTypeFormatter> formatters;
            return ResolveType(api, controllerName, actionName, parameterNames, SampleDirection.Request, out formatters);
        }

public virtual Type ResolveType(ApiDescription api, string controllerName, string actionName, IEnumerable<string> parameterNames, SampleDirection sampleDirection, out Collection<MediaTypeFormatter> formatters)
        {
            if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(SampleDirection), sampleDirection))
            {
                throw new InvalidEnumArgumentException("sampleDirection", (int)sampleDirection, typeof(SampleDirection));
            }
            if (api == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("api");
            }
            Type type;
            if (ActualHttpMessageTypes.TryGetValue(new HelpPageSampleKey(sampleDirection, controllerName, actionName, parameterNames), out type) ||
                ActualHttpMessageTypes.TryGetValue(new HelpPageSampleKey(sampleDirection, controllerName, actionName, new[] { "*" }), out type))
            {
                // Re-compute the supported formatters based on type
                Collection<MediaTypeFormatter> newFormatters = new Collection<MediaTypeFormatter>();
                foreach (var formatter in api.ActionDescriptor.Configuration.Formatters)
                {
                    if (IsFormatSupported(sampleDirection, formatter, type))
                    {
                        newFormatters.Add(formatter);
                    }
                }
                formatters = newFormatters;
            }
            else
            {
                switch (sampleDirection)
                {
                    case SampleDirection.Request:
                        ApiParameterDescription requestBodyParameter = api.ParameterDescriptions.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Source == ApiParameterSource.FromBody);
                        type = requestBodyParameter == null ? null : requestBodyParameter.ParameterDescriptor.ParameterType;
                        formatters = api.SupportedRequestBodyFormatters;
                        break;
                    case SampleDirection.Response:
                    default:
                        type = api.ResponseDescription.ResponseType ?? api.ResponseDescription.DeclaredType;
                        formatters = api.SupportedResponseFormatters;
                        break;
                }
            }

            return type;
        }
```

I am not sure why `formatters` is passed as an out parameters but its being detected as an unused variable.

**UPDATE 2:**
**Another example:**

```
if (statusBar.IsFrozen(out int frozen) == 0)
{
    statusBar.SetText(statusBarText);
}
```

Here variable `frozen` is detected as an unused variable.
I couldn't access the property "DeclarationKind" (image below). So that I can add a condition like ,

```
if(unusedVar.DeclarationKind=="OutVariable") continue;
```

[[image: DeclarationKind]]

Comment: so is the variable `data` actually used?

Comment: yes, it is used.

Comment: @JohnB I edited m E.g. code. num variable is being used in my code.

Comment: ok, sorry i'm stumped...

Comment: You've only shown us code where the variable is *assigned*. It's not read in that snippet.

Comment: Sorry for the bad example. I updated the real e.g.code in question where I got this problem.

Comment: Even with your updated code, I don't see anywhere where `formatters` is *read from* as opposed to *written to*.

Comment: yeah thats a autogenerated code in my webapi project where formatters is being passed as a paramter to ResolveType method. Still VS 2017 inbuilt _resharper is not detecting_ formatters as an unused variable. But my GetUnusedVariables() is detecting it. Am I missing something in my analyzer code.

Comment: build the solution and in the error list tab you wull have warnings like xyz is never assigned to and will always have its default value

Comment: I suggest to use [`FindReferences`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.codeanalysis.findsymbols.symbolfinder.findreferencesasync?view=roslyn-dotnet#Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_FindSymbols_SymbolFinder_FindReferencesAsync_Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_ISymbol_Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_Solution_System_Collections_Immutable_IImmutableSet_Microsoft_CodeAnalysis_Document__System_Threading_CancellationToken_) for local variable inside the current document and check that the find count 0 or 1 (I'm not remember about self declaration as part of references)